# How to enable CORS in Grails 3.0.1

Tags: grails, cors, grails-3.0

I would like to do cross origin communication using Grails in server side. The only documentation that I found is this one

https://grails.org/plugin/cors

but this is for an old version of Grails. The other documentation that I found is for spring:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

so I added  the file `SimpleCorsFilter.groovy` to `init/myproject/` folder, but I don't know how to wire this component into `resources.groovy`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So, if you got here **using grails 3.2.+** you can use the default way.

Go to your `application.yml` and add:

```
grails:
    cors:
        enabled: true
```

It will add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'`.
If you want something different, [look this page](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#cors)

Comment: what is the solution for Grails 2.5.0 ? i am getting `from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: This works if your backend server and client are running HTTP. If SSL is enabled, this is no longer sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

We used a normal servlet filter with an entry in resources.groovy to solve this problem:

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

        boolean options = "OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod());
        if (options) {
            if (origin == null) return;
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        }

        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin == null ? "*" : origin);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!options) chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    corsFilter(CorsFilter)
}
```

This works with CORS requests using basic authentication. I wrote the Grails 2.x plugin and this seemed easier than getting it to work with Grails 3.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I'm using Grails 2.5.4, and creating the `CorsFilter` class in src/groovy and then defining the bean in **resources.groovy** didn't wire up the filter.

Comment: Never mind. I misunderstood the comment. Using the Grails 2.x plugin here seems to be working for me: https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors Thanks David!

Answer (score 9):

To be specific, here is some code that works. Notice the interceptor name must match your controller name (here, workRequest), the domain needs to be whatever you are calling from (here, localhost:8081) and it is the before() method you want:

```
package rest
class WorkRequestInterceptor {
boolean before() { 
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE" )
    header( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600" )  
    true 
}

boolean after() { true }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was playing around with the emberjs framework together with a Grails 3.0 rest application when I was hit by the CORS issue. Following the steps in this article http://www.greggbolinger.com/rendering-json-in-grails-for-ember-js/ helped me get further.

The article shows how you can use the new Interceptors to create a CorsInterceptor class which sets the correct headers.

```
class CorsInterceptor {

  CorsInterceptor() {
    matchAll()
  }

  boolean before() {
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
    header( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600" )
    true
  }

  boolean after() { true }
}
```

This worked as expected for GET requests, but failed for POST and PUT requests. The reason for this was that an OPTIONS preflight request was sent first to http://localhost:8080/mycontroller/1234, which in my case caused a *404 not found* to be returned.

With the help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31834551 I modified the CorsInterceptor class to this instead:

```
class CorsInterceptor {

   CorsInterceptor() {
    matchAll()
  }

  boolean before() {
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200" )
    boolean options = ("OPTIONS" == request.method)
    if (options) {

        header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200" )
        header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" )
        header( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
        header( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600" )

        response.status = 200
    }

    true 
  }

  boolean after() { true }

}
```

Now POST and PUT requests were working.

Answer (score 3):

You should use grails 3's new Interceptor API. (https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#interceptors)

You can create an interceptor with the `grails create-interceptor` command. For a CORS Interceptor I would use the `after()` method of this Interceptor, and set it up to match all requests (or just the requests you need). You can use the `response` object in this method, so setting the headers should be similar to the case described in the Spring documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest and simplest solution for grails 3.1.x I found is to add the Apache default CorsFilter:

```
import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    corsFilter(CorsFilter) //Custom CorsFilter under src/main/java/ works as well. I prefer Apache though...
}
```

The answer from #user215556 works as well but the default setting of the Apache Cors filter is ok as well

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enable CORS for endpoints provided by the Spring Security core/rest plugins you have to add this:

Bootstrap.groovy:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter("corsFilter",
    SecurityFilterPosition.SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER.order - 1)
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    corsFilter(CorsFilter)
}
```