# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when serving javascript file to external sites

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

My site provides a javascript file which the users can include in their site. This javascript file in-turn calls my applications endpoint and fetches some content that is then inputted into the users' `div`

This is the code for the JS

```
(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var test = $('#FooBar');
        var id = test.data('id');
        $.get('http://example.com/serve/'+id, function(data){
            test.html(data);
        });
    });
})();
```

But when a user references this JS file on their own site, they get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://example.com/serve/qeFz7TvGlg.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

This is the sample HTML I created to test

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="FooBar" data-id="qeFz7TvGlg"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://example.com/scripts/myjsfile.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What language is your web server written in?

Comment: It is written in Grails

Comment: Cool check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584164/how-to-enable-cors-in-grails-3-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs to specify the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (probably to `*`, which means "all"). This is called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

To give a naive example, here's how you might do that in node.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

## Edit

Since your server is in Grails, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584164/how-to-enable-cors-in-grails-3-0-1) about how to enable CORS.

Comment: So, the webserver for my application (the one that is providing the JS file to customers) should add ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin ` to `*` when responding to the API call?

Comment: Yep, something like that. You can configure the header however you want. You can specify only certain origins, or you can use all origins. I would suggest taking a look at the CORS link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Grails Server, look at [this](http://www.a86.be/blog/how-to-solve-the-access-control-allow-origin-when-calling-a-restful-grails-application-from-angularjs/) link. You should be able to open or create a web.xml file and copy the contents on the website into there.